$\oint_{|z| = 2/3}f(z)dz$

Let
$$f(z) = \frac{4z^2+1}{z^2(e^{\pi i/z}-1)}$$
and evaluate
$$\oint_{|z| = 2/3}f(z)dz$$


I want to use the residue theorem for this one so I search for singularities and surely $z=0$ is one of them and also
$$e^{\pi i/z}-1 = 0 \iff z_k = \frac{1}{2k}, k \in \Bbb Z$$
here I notice that singularities accumulate in zero hence the origin isn't an isolated singularity. So taking inspiration from this answer, let $w = 1/z,dw = -\frac{1}{z^2}dz$, I think that
$$\oint_{|z| = 2/3}f(z)dz = -\oint_{|w| = 3/2} \frac{4+w^2}{w^2(e^{\pi i w}-1)}dw=:I$$
and inside this circle we have only three singularities in $z = 0, \pm 1$ so for the residue theorem
$$I = \sum_{z=0,\pm1}\text{Res}_f(z)$$
and while I'm having some issues evaluating $z=0$(which I think it's a 2-pole) residue, $z=\pm1$ are 1-pole so a little bit easier I'm interested in understanding if this is a valid approach or I should take another way in order to solve this.

Thank you very much, any help is appreciated!

Your approach is sound, except for a small detail about the residues at $w=\pm1$. Those poles are not there. When $w$ is an odd integer $\exp(i\pi w)$ is $-1$, not $+1$ (watch your signs!), so subtracting $1$ from the exponential does not give a zero factor in the denominator. That leaves the residue at $w=0$.
Yes, finding this residue is a little tricky as you indeed have a higher order pole there. There are firmulae for that based on derivatives, but that will bog you down when you have a fairly complicated functiin to differentiate. A better way is to convert tge function to the form $f(w)/w^n$ where $n$ is the order of the pole and the coefficient of $w^{n-1}$ in the Maclaurin series gives the residue.
So we first identify $n=2$, oh wait a minute $n=3$ because $\exp(iw)-1$ introduces a factor proportional to $w$ as $w\to0$.
We render
$w^2(\exp(i\pi w)-1)=w^3\left(\dfrac{\exp(i\pi w)-1}{w}\right)$
where the term in thevlarge parentheses has the limit $i\pi\not=0$ and thus, properly, the pole is third order.
We will need the Maclaurin series expansion out to terms of order $w^2$ for a third order pole, so using the series expansion for the exponential function the following is taken:
$\dfrac{\exp(i\pi w)-1}{w}\sim(i\pi)\left(1+\dfrac{i\pi w}{2}-\dfrac{pi^2w^2}{6}\right)$
Now we have to take the multiplicative inverse to put into the numeratir $f(w)$. Render
$\left(1+\dfrac{i\pi}{2}-\dfrac{pi^2}{6}\right)\left(1+aw+bw^2\right)=1,$
where we match terms of ordrr $w^1$ to get $a=-i\pi/2$ and then katch the $w^2$ terms to get $b=-\pi^2/12$. We do not need terms with three or more powers of $w$ for tge residue of third-order pole, so those are ignored.
So we end up with
$\dfrac{w^2+4}{\exp(i\pi w)-1}\sim\dfrac{[(w^2+4)/i\pi][1-(i\pi/2)w-(\pi^2/12)w^2]}{w^3},$
whose residue at $w=0$ can now be read off after expanding the product in the numerator.
Continue from there.

Actually I forgot that poles are on even integers as you highlighted, whoops... Btw so this process is analogous to find the residue at $\infty$ of the function if I'm not mistaken

Exactly. While it is technically possible to do this integral without this inversion (for a limit-point singularity the residue can still be defined), this appproach is superior.

Find the Laurent Series expansion of $\frac{1}{w^{2}(e^{i\pi w}-1)}$
You have $w^{2}(e^{i\pi w}-1)=w^{2}(\frac{w i\pi}{1}-\frac{\pi^{2}w^{2}}{2!}-\frac{iw^{3}\pi^{3}}{3!}+...)=i\pi w^{3}(1-\frac{\pi w}{2i}-\frac{w^{2}\pi^{2}}{6}+...)$
So $$\frac{1}{i\pi w^{3}(1-\frac{\pi w}{2i}-\frac{w^{2}\pi^{2}}{6}+...)}=\frac{1}{i\pi w^{3}}\bigg(1+\frac{\pi w}{2}+\frac{w^{2}\pi^{2}}{6}+(\frac{\pi w}{2i})^{2}+\{\text{higher powers of} \,w\}\bigg)$$
So $$\frac{4+w^{2}}{w^{2}(e^{i\pi w}-1)}=\frac{4\pi}{6i w}-\frac{4\pi}{i4w}+\frac{1}{i\pi w}+\text{other terms}$$
So the residue at $0$ is $\displaystyle \frac{ i\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{i\pi}$

To find the Laurent series of the integrand start with the well-known Maclaurin series $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n.$ We have
$$g(w)=\frac{4+w^2}{w^2(e^{\pi iw}-1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4B_n(\pi i)^{n-1}}{n!}w^{n-3}
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n(\pi i)^{n-1}}{n!}w^{n-1}$$
Hence, noting that $B_0=1, B_2=\frac16$,
$$Res_{z=0}\,g(w)=\frac{4B_2(\pi i)^{2-1}}{2!}+\frac{B_0(\pi i)^{0-1}}{0!}=\frac{3-\pi^2}{3\pi i}.$$
I think since the orientation of the curve changes after the substitution, and there are no other poles, the answer is
$$I=\color{red}{+}2\pi i(Res_{z=0}\,g(w))=2-\frac23\pi^2.$$
